# Youtube API v3 Playlistitems returns different order than on youtube.com

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

I'm creating a script that grabs the newest videos from the uploaded videos from a channel. It remembers which video it processed last and if it comes across that same videoId it quits. This works beautifully, until I cam across a playlist that does not have the newest added video at position 1 in its uploaded playlist.

The strangest thing however, is that on youtube.com the same playlist does have the correct order:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_HvPmd9L9o&list=UUpsSadsgX_Qk9i6i_bJoUwQ

But in the Youtube API response the order is different:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2C+contentDetails&maxResults=50&playlistId={YOUR API KEY}&key=AIzaSyBtO0Bl38DJKCuPh9e4mRW3-1UcGPPnQfs
```

Is it something that i'm doing wrong with my API call or is this a bug in youtube? I can't find an option to sort playlistitems by date or anything.

Which got me thinking, when users create playlist they are usually ordered from oldest added -> newest added. Do you have to call all pages just to get the newest added? That seems to be madness.

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube API for retrieving the playlist from a channel does not provide any parameter where we can set the order in which we want to retrieve the playlist. We do not have how the internal algorithm for fetching the video data works. But from your analysis it seems that the UI API on the live site is different from the data retrieved from the API's.

Although the [***yt:position***](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:position) tag specifies the order in which a video appears in a playlist.

Example

```
<yt:position>4</yt:position>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see it lists them in upload order.

Let's assume you are batch uploading episodes 1-5 of a series. 
You select the five videos and drag into the upload window. YT will upload them in the order it was given by your OS (often #1, #5, then #'s 4, 3 & 2).

You can set the videos to publish on successive days: #1 on Monday, #2 on Tuesday etc. which will show in the correct order on your channel page.

The API call will only bring back published videos so if you make the call on Weds after #3 is published, you will get 3 videos in your response [probably] ordered #1, #3 & #2.